# What is the average of $\DeclareMathOperator{\rect}{rect} \rect(\cos(\pi t/2)) $?

Tags: continuous-signals, self-study, averaging

We have this signal:

$$\operatorname{rect}\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi t} {2}\right)\right) $$

I must find the average power , how can i get there ?

**My solution:**

I have seen that
$$-\frac 12 < \operatorname{rect}\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi t}{2}\right)\right) < 1$$
is for
$$\frac 23+k \pi <t < \frac 43 + k\pi$$
so in a period it should be rectangular pulse , but how do I calculate the average ?

Comment: Hi! Homework ? Online-Quiz ? Where have you been stuck ? What's that rect() function ?

Comment: Hi , rect is the function that is 1 between  -1/2 <t < 1/2

Comment: Good! So what's the problem ?

Comment: and i was doing this exercise and i got 1/3 as average , but i have written that  it should be 1/2 , so which one is correct ?

Comment: Put your solution lines into your question...

Comment: yes , i 've tried to do that

Comment: You need to show how you arrived at your result. Then we can tell where you went wrong.

Comment: Just to be clear - are you sure you don't mean $rect() \cdot \cos(\pi t/2)$? So a rect window multiplied by a cosine instead of a cosine inside a rect window.

Comment: The average power...

Comment: is 1/3 the average ?

Answer (score 2):

The given signal is clearly periodic. So just follow these steps and find the solution:

1. Find the period $T$.
2. Figure out the interval within a period for which the signal equals $1$.
3. Compute the average: $$\overline{x(t)}=\frac{1}{T}\int_0^Tx(t)dt$$

If you're convinced that you did everything right, don't worry about a given solution which is different.

Comment: Doing this i find that the period is 4 , and the average is 1/3 is it right ?

Comment: @GiovanniCerciello: Sounds like a reasonable result.